# Return the number of times (including 0 times) an id from one table appears in another table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables and want to find how many times the id from the first table (labels) appear in the other table (article_labels), but also when it doesn't (I want it to return 0 when it doesn't). I Use MySQL and PHP. I prefer a solution that involves just MySQL.

The tables are:

```
LABELS (table 1)
+--+---------------+
|ID|EN             |
+--+---------------+
|1 |"Artert"       |
+--+---------------+
|2 |"Heart"        |
+--+---------------+
|3 |"Brain"        |
+--+---------------+


ARTICLE_LABELS (table 2)
+--+------------+
|ID|LABELID     |
+--+------------+
|1 |2           |
+--+------------+
|2 |1           |
+--+------------+
|3 |1           |
+--+------------+
|4 |1           |
+--+------------+
|5 |2           |
+--+------------+
```

I have a query that works fine, but I want a row in the result set even though the id from the labels table does not appear in the article_labels table (as is the case for id 3 in the labels table above).

My current query is:

```
SELECT labels.id, en, COUNT( * ) AS used
FROM article_labels
LEFT JOIN labels ON labelid = labels.id
GROUP BY labelid
```

This will return:

```
+--+---------------+
|ID|EN     |USED   |
+--+---------------+
|1 |Artery | 3     |
+--+---------------+
|2 |Heart  | 2     |
+--+---------------+
```

But as expected it doesn't show the labels.id 3 in the result set since it doesn't appear in the article_labels table. But I wan't a query that also returns the "id = 3" and "en = Brain" from the labels table even though it doesn't appear in the article_labels table (the result would look like this):

```
+--+---------------+
|ID|EN     |USED   |
+--+---------------+
|1 |Artery | 3     |
+--+---------------+
|2 |Heart  | 2     |
+--+---------------+
|3 |Brain  | 0     |
+--+---------------+
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a `RIGHT JOIN` instead of a `LEFT JOIN` (or else swap the order in which you join the tables); you also need to name the column that you wish to count, as you want to exclude those records that are `NULL` from the join:

```
SELECT   l.id, COUNT(al.labelid) AS used
FROM     article_labels al RIGHT JOIN labels l ON al.labelid = l.id
GROUP BY l.id
```

Or

```
SELECT   l.id, COUNT(al.labelid) AS used
FROM     labels l LEFT JOIN article_labels al ON al.labelid = l.id
GROUP BY l.id
```

See them on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f891/1).

See [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) for more information.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Works just the way I wanted to!

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a good case for a subselect:

```
SELECT labels.id, 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM article_labels WHERE labelid=labels.id) AS used
 FROM labels;
```

Comment: This is also exactly what I was looking for. Produces the desired result just as the above answer.